# What is the value of this shunt resistor from a drone power distribution board?

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, identification, shunt

What is the value of the shunt resistor shown below? It is from the drone power distribution board, rated for up to 120 A. I am guessing, that the value is 0.25 mOhm. However, even with this value, at max current, power dissipation is ~3.6 W, which is way above the typical 2 W power rating.

[image: Shunt resistor]

Comment: You've got the right value. It'll just melt and fall off if it stays at that too high. There are a lot of vias there though so maybe enough heat is sinked through the board. Also it's not totally uncommon to see boards over-rated for how much power they can accept/produce.

Comment: If those are 1206 MLCCs next to it then the size of that shunt does not look like 2W to me. It looks more like 5-7W but I am basing this off the size of exposed solid metal shunts, so I may be off base here. The resistor power rating is also for still air. But on a quadcopter there's also airflow though not nearly as much as a fixed wing UAV.

Comment: Also can't imagine a drone would draw those 120 A for any extended time (few seconds maybe?). 'Duty cycle' is probably significantly below unity.